# Is there a Stack Exchange site for asking a question about user experience of a bug in GeoGebra?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I posted [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35813/geogebra-6-classic-has-updated-i-have-a-problem-do-you-have-it-too) about a certain user experience of a bug in the latest version of GeoGebra on MathematicsMeta. It got closed in no time on the grounds that it is off-topic. I agree. I would like to know whether there is a Stack Exchange site for asking a question of this nature.

An Edit:

The question I referred to in the above text was deleted by Stack Exchange

This is the summary of my original post at MathematicsMeta:

I am using Windows 10 and Geogebra-6-Classic. It has automatically updated twice in the recent past. On 26th June it was updated to version 6.0.783 and the next day to version 6.0.785. Now I have a problem with the command **Save to your Computer**, which has already ruined three of my GGB-files since 26th June, by simply emptying their content before saving them, so that the files have size 0 kb. I have only realized this on 27th June when I lost my third file. So, I downloaded the latest installable version from GeoGebra site and installed it again hoping that the possible error or bug would go away. It did not.

Before reporting this to GeoGebra, I would like to know whether it is only for me. Hope someone will let me know, if he/she is experiencing the same problem.

**Final Edit**

I have emailed GeoGebra-Support at **support@geogebra.org** about the bug. They have replied acknowledging the existence of this bug in the version 6.0.785. They also informed me that they have patched it successfully in versions newer than 6.0.785.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not outsourced bug tracker. Report it to GeoGebra.

Comment: @user3840170 My question is not about bug tracking. I am trying to figure out whether other users of GeoGebra (specially geometricians) have experience a problem I am having with the latest version of GeoGebra. At the same time, I want to caution them. Once I find out that others also have the same problem, I will try to report it to Geogebra.

Comment: That's usually something you do on a bug tracker, on maybe on the <software>'s community discord.

Comment: @Cerbrus When you say <software>'s community discord, you mean a kind of forum, ok? There is a post [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/geogebra/comments/14kk8oe/save_geogebra_classic_6_files_on_computer_laptop/). But its outcome is still inconclusive. I want to post my question in Stack Exchange, simply because I want to warn the fellow geometricians to prevent them losing the content of their GGB-files.

Comment: @YNK And the answers you're getting are **That's not what Stack Exchange is for**. Simple as that. If you don't have a question that needs an answer, this isn't the correct site.

Comment: @Esther If you read my question (not my last comment), you know that I have asked a question. Unfortunately, you have entered this discussion too late to know that I have got an answer. But the comment containing that answer was deleted for some reason. I think it is better if we stop commenting on my question. Thanks for all who participated.

Comment: While links to external content, including links to posts from SE communities, might be helpful, questions here or on SO and andy SE community should be self-contained. You might remove the link, add the relevant parts, a summery or, if the post is not too long, the whole content.

Comment: What do you mean by "user experience of a bug"?

Comment: @ Rubén-PeopleFirst Since I posted my question at MathematicsMeta I was dodging bullets. I survived, but my post didn’t - first closed and then deleted. After that post got closed, I posted this question on Stack Exchange Meta. Just as Wicket (that is you ok?) has done in his answer below, another answerer suggested me the site Super User, but he/she deleted it for a reason unknown to me. I might post my question there once I gather some courage to face more bullets. In the meantime, as you have instructed, I have already added a summary of my question to the body of my post.

Comment: @YNK This is an alternate account of Rubén-PeopleFirst. I still have to use both accounts but eventually, I will delete Rubén and request the relation of Rubén posts with Wicket (once I solve some issues). While I understand that you are sharing your feelings. On posts about technical stuff like where to ask a question, I suggest keeping the content focused on the technical parts, side comments and chat might have the feeling and impression parts. I mention this because the phrase "user experience of a bug" looks to be a mix. That kind of post might be OK in other places, but as have seen...

Comment: ... they are not well received here. I will update my answer.

Comment: You might try here: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/search?q=geoGebra https://askubuntu.com/search?q=GeoGebra - but check the help (?) to make certain that you phrase the question on-topic.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for your answer. The site MathematicsEducators of StackExchange is for posting questions about teaching mathematics, I have already found the site for posting my question, i.e. SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the recently added content, your question seems on-topic in [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Tip: Don't use "user experience of a bug". Describe the problem using simple words, including textual error messages, the step by step instructions and all the relevant details necessary to reproduce the problem. If something is hard to describe textually, add a screenshot.

---

What you mean by "user experience of a bug" is unclear. I don't know the details of GeoGebra, like the system requirements, if is cross-platform software, etc. As mentioned in the comments, Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sites are not issue / bug trackers. These sites are not service desks or customer support site replacements for what the software developer / company should do.

Anyway, here are some sites that you might take a look into

There is a site called [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). Their Tour introduction says:

> UX Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for User Experience Designers, Information Architects, and Human Computer Interaction researchers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about user experience.

There is a site called [Super User](https://superuser.com). Their Tour introduction says:

> Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about computer software or hardware.

According to discussions on Super User Meta, they might help with troubleshooting-like questions but bear in mind that the system is not well suited for these kinds of questions as they usually require a lot of back and forth. IMO, troubleshooting help could be got only if someone offers to help. Good luck.

Please review the tour page thoroughly and the Ask Question page, including all the user guidance and the linked resources, i.e., How to ask a good question.

Comment: I don’t know why the two answers including yours getting down-votes. It looks like that sympathizers are also under fire. The expression **user experience of a bug** here means users’ experience when they have a bug in a software. they are using.

Answer (score -2):

I think you've been treated somewhat harshly. Just like [StackOverflow accepts questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), similarly [Mathematics accepts questions about "Software that mathematicians use (except Mathematica, which has its own Stack Exchange site)"](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Now, with your question having been deleted I can't talk about the specific thing you posted, but it seems to me that *something like* "Is there a workaround for this bug in GeoGebra" would be on topic. Maybe ask [on Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/), or in [its main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics), for help refining your ideas into a 'good' post?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have just added a summary of my original question to the body of my post

Comment: A question about a bug on GeoGebra would almost certainly be off-topic on [mathematics.se].  In this particular case, the bug (posted to Math SE) was about a failure of a document to save.  This is not a math question, but a bug which should be reported to GeoGebra, or discussed on the GeoGebra support fora.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thank you. I have already emailed GeoGebra-Support at **support@geogebra.org** about the bug. They have replied acknowledging the existence of this bug in the version 6.0.785, which cost me three GGB-files. They also informed me that they have patched it successfully in versions newer than 6.0.785.